# How to make image in a comment box smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a comment box, I want the image to be smaller than the dimensions of the box. Please help
 My current code:

```
<div style="border: 0px solid black; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;background-color:white;">
    <p style="float: left;font-size:12px; "></p>

    <img alt="2" src="Imgs/test.png">
    <b>danny Boyle:</b>
    "This is a test comment "
</div>
```

This is what I want to produce:

[image: This is what I am looking for]

Comment: Can you clarify what you've tried? What's the empty `<p>` for?

Comment: The image and the comment border is the same I need a space/padding of the image from the comment box as well keeping in mind of the responsiveness of the page

Comment: You clearly know CSS so you must have attempted *something*. I'll give a hint: `padding`

Comment: But, the page doesn't remains responsive then? I am using Twitter Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap, then *use it* the most you can. There are a few tools to do what you want, namely the [Media Object](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#media) styles:

Change up your markup:

```
<div class="media my-media">
  <img class="pull-left media-object" src="your/image.jpg">
  <div class="media-body">
      <p><b>danny Boyle:</b></p>
      <p>"This is a test comment"</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added the class `my-media` so we can do something custom:

```
.my-media {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqxgy/ (<sub><sup>The grey border on the image is actually in your avatar</sup></sub>)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Moving away from inline styles and adjusting your elements a little, you can achieve the results you'd like (check out [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fsmJi) for the results in action):

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="img"><img alt="2" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></div>
    <span>danny Boyle:</span>
    "This is a test comment "
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  border: 0px solid black; 
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;
  background-color:white;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.box .img {
  float:left;
  font-size:12px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.box img {
  max-width:100%;
}
.box span {
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.box:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  content:"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the image tag in HTML, you can specify/restrict the height and width of the image, so you should be able to limit its size that way.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

So:

```
 <div style="border: 0px solid black; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;background-      color:white;">
    <p style="float: left;font-size:12px; "></p>

    <img alt="2" src="Imgs/test.png" height="X" width="Y">
    <b>danny Boyle:</b>
    "This is a test comment "
</div>
```

Comment: I have used Twitter Bootstrap, would it remain responsive then?

Comment: While I haven't used Twitter Bootstrap, I couldn't see why not as it's only adjusting the basic attributes of the tag itself, in this case its size.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following (Image is bigger than the Box dimensions defined in css):

```
<div id="Box" >
<img id="Image1" src="http://fianbakken.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/logo.png" />
```

With the following style:

```
#Box {

    background-color: #f00;
    width:200px; 
    height:300px; 
    overflow:none;
}
```

You can scale the image with JQuery, e.g. something like following:

```
if($("#Image1").width() >= $("#Box").width()){
   $("#Image1").width($("#Box").width()-20);
}

if($("#Image1").height() >= $("#Box").height()){
   $("#Image1").height($("#Box").height()-20);
}
```

I put up a little JSFiddle to illustrate the example

http://jsfiddle.net/7qnyQ/8/

Comment: Using jQuery to scale the image is a little overkill. Simply choosing to give the image a max-width and its container a fixed width achieves the same results.

Comment: Yeah, this is like shooting a squirrel with a bazooka, sort of unnecessary. The CSS solution is the better way.